# Airbnb.com logo like animation

Tags: animation, css

How does [airbnb.com](http://airbnb.com) achieves the animation when you mouse over the logo ? I think it uses css3 but I wasn't fully able to understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, it uses CSS3 animation:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)
  }

  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,5deg)
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,-5deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }

  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg)
  }

  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg)
  }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

#logo:hover {
  -webkit-animation: wiggle .2s ease-in-out alternate;
  -moz-animation: wiggle .2s ease-in-out alternate;
  -ms-animation: wiggle .2s ease-in-out alternate
}

#logo:hover img {
  opacity: .8;
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=80)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=80)
}
```

Comment: It works fantastic on Firefox and Safari but strangely enough not on Chrome. Do you happen to know why that might be?

Comment: @PericlesThedorou this worked in Chrome 24 but stopped working in Chrome 25.  Does anyone know why?  And how to make it work in Chrome again?  https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/aoavVOPxTmE

Comment: @Ryan: Strangely enough, http://airbnb.com doesn't work for me on the latest Firefox Nightly, too.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov yeah I think Airbnb changed their source code soon after Chrome 25 came out.  I don't think they do the wiggle anymore on any browser (though I haven't looked closely).

Comment: @Ryan: according to the comments on https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112274, the CSS on airbnb.com is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the code of the website.

Per http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-functions, `rotate3d(<number>, <number>, <number>, <angle>)` specifies a 3D rotation by the angle specified in last parameter about the `[x,y,z]` direction vector described by the first three parameters. A direction vector that cannot be normalized, such as `[0,0,0]`, will cause the rotation to not be applied.

For WebKit based browser the site was doing `-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)` in the keyframes which is an invalid value and therefore should be rejected. You want to do `-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)` instead.

So every browser aligns to that behaviour so I'd say that it's a content issue.

Tracked by https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112274 inside WebKit but it's very likely that we'll close the bug without doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

My solution for this is similar to the one submitted by Pavlov. As of this posting, it works Chrome 25 and 26, and earlier versions - I developed this close to a year ago, and it has worked in all versions.

```
.logo:hover {
-webkit-animation: wiggle .15s 2 ease;
-moz-animation: wiggle .15s 2 ease;
-o-animation: wiggle .15s 2 ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wiggle {
from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
from { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
}

@-moz-keyframes wiggle {
from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
from { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
}

@-o-keyframes wiggle {
from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -o-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
from { -o-transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
to { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0px); }
}
```